# Can't Reset iMac on Big Sur

Tags: macos, recovery, internet-recovery, big-sur, restart

I'm having an annoying issue. I can boot into MacOS but I cannot for the life of me boot into recovery mode, internet recovery mode, startup disk mode, safe mode, etc. I can boot into the OS without any issues, but I want to reset the Mac because I'm getting rid of it soon. I was using a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse so I thought that may have been an issue. I turned off Bluetooth and connected a wired KB + mouse... still nothing. I tried another KB and... still nothing.

I have created a Catalina boot USB... but I can't even get to the screen to try to boot into that.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Does it help to do a SMC and PRAM reset?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you trying to boot into Recovery Mode as explained here: https://support.apple.com/HT204904 and here: https://support.apple.com/HT201314? What happens when you press Command-R? To start up from your USB drive, open System Preferences and change the startup disk as explained here: https://support.apple.com/HT202796.